# HTML Table formatting : problem with rowspan = 0

Tags: html

Hi considering the following snippet and image :

[image]

I'm having a hard time trying to make the last row of tbody's height filling the first cell height.  Rowspan =0 is supposed to let the TD spanning as many rows as there is in the tbody group.

I'm asking this because this table is dynamically generated by imbricated foreach blocks.

Any ideas on this ?

Thanks!

```html
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td{
width: 90px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The td rowspan attribute</h1>

<table>

  <tr>
    <th >Month</th>
    <th >Savings</th>
    <th >Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<tbody> 
  <tr>
  <td rowspan=0>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  <tr >
    <td >February</td>
    <td >$80</td>
  </tr>
  
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your'e right !  here it is !

Comment: i've starting trying to do it with jquery, but if by any chance there's a quicker way via css, I'll take it ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem with a small piece of jquery :

```
 function PaddingHauteurActions() {

$("tbody").each(function (index) {

  var mytbody = $(this);
  var mytbodyHeight = mytbody.height();
  var actionHeight = 0;
  mytbody.find("tr.action")
    .each(function (index) { actionHeight += $(this).height(); });

  // 8 is for row top padding ....
  if (mytbodyHeight > actionHeight)
    mytbody.find("tr:last-child.action >td:first-child").css('padding-bottom', mytbodyHeight + 8 - actionHeight);

});
```

}